# Simple html dom find not starting with

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

How to find elements using `simple_html_dom` that their attributes not starting with certain string ?

For example i don't want to find these elements :

```
<a href="/files/adv/568">Title</a>
<a href="/files/adv/201">Title</a>
```

I don't want to find `a` tag that its `href` starting with `/files/adv/`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming their selector engine supports selectors level 3:

```
$html->find('a:not([href^="/files/adv/"])');
```

If not, you'll need to just search for all `a` elements and loop over them to check what their href attribute is.

Comment: Does the error indicate that selector syntax is not supported, or was it some other problem?

Comment: Nothing happens. Even using this :
`$html->find('a:notsssss([href^="/files/adv/"])');`